Debian 12 Geo clue demo agent
Debian 12 has under settings "sessions and startup" ,"application autostart" a value called "geoclue demo agent"
What is the function of this startup and how is it used ?

https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/geoclue/geoclue/-/wikis/home

Is it possible to determine what application use geolocation by default on Debian 12 ?

Welcome this site. This isn't a forum where threaded conversations, new questions, and asides are the norm. This site requires single, specific questions that can be answered with specificity. As such, do not add new questions in comments. Also, questions are better received when they demonstrate some effort on your part, at least some research or digging you did yourself. I would guess this question could have been answered with a quick web search.
